# Excel: How to construct an achievement schedule based on Working Day with known intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have a calendar schedule where i track achievements that should be occurring every 10 days between a start and finish period. I want to skip Sundays and Public holidays.
The issue i currently have, is if the 10th day falls on a Sunday / PH then the value is skipped.
Ideally, the achievement should be reached on the day following a Sunday or PH.

The point behind the schedule, is create an Scurve. Based on weekly achievements over a year. However i'd like to avoid adding them manually into excel.

Below is an example, where the **1** is where the formula should return it's first achievement

```
    Production  DAYS    10
    Start Date      31/12/2021
    End date        28/07/2022
    

   Week  Day        Date       Achievement
    1   Thursday    30/12/2021  0
    1   Friday      31/12/2021  0
    1   Saturday    1/01/2022   0
    1   Sunday      2/01/2022   0
    1   Monday      3/01/2022   0
    1   Tuesday     4/01/2022   0
    1   Wednesday   5/01/2022   0
    2   Thursday    6/01/2022   0
    2   Friday      7/01/2022   0
    2   Saturday    8/01/2022   0
    2   Sunday      9/01/2022   0
    2   Monday      10/01/2022  0
    2   Tuesday     11/01/2022  0
    2   Wednesday   12/01/2022  **1**
    3   Thursday    13/01/2022  0
    3   Friday      14/01/2022  0
    3   Saturday    15/01/2022  0
    3   Sunday      16/01/2022  0
    3   Monday      17/01/2022  0
    3   Tuesday     18/01/2022  0
    3   Wednesday   19/01/2022  0
    4   Thursday    20/01/2022  0
    4   Friday      21/01/2022  0
    4   Saturday    22/01/2022  0
    4   Sunday      23/01/2022  0
    4   Monday      24/01/2022  **1**
    4   Tuesday     25/01/2022  0
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. There is some ambiguity in your question. Your list of dates starts on 30/12/2021 (Thursday) but your "Start Date" is stated as 31/12/2021 (a Friday). You have highlighted the date of 8/1/2022 (Saturday, a weekend date by most definitions) which is either the eighth or ninth day after the Start Date (depending on whether period is inclusive of Start Date or not). Additionally, do you want day 10 on a rolling basis or do you want to divide your 7 month Start to End  period into consecutive, exclusive periods each of 10 working days

Comment: So 10 working days is a cycle without Sunday/PH?

Comment: Thanks DMM and Lee- 
Start date and where the calendar starts, shouldn't impact the rolling basis (though do get the initial query was incorrectly placed). Sorry for that. 

This should be a rolling basis/ cycle that skips without Sunday / PH. We work a 6D week 

:( 

Will be trying to cut off the rolling basis / cycle off at the end date. 

I updated the query as i've had a little more luck on my side. Though it's turned into an exceptionally convoluted series of "if statements". Which seem over the top and cumbersome to manage. Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a very nice function call WORKDAY.INTL you can use.

First define all your public holidays somewhere e.g. in range Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10.

Now setup your work calendar to list only workdays. If C7 is equal to your start date, then in C8 (and copy-paste downwards):

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(C7,1,11,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10)
```

Since we are only listing workdays, we simply have to count rows to determine if its a 10th/achievement day. In D6 (and copy-paste downwards):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(D1),10)=0, 1, 0)
```